# How can I move an email message from All mail to Trash using imaplib and gmail

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib

I want to delete an email from my Inbox using imaplib and gmail. The problem is that the email is moved from Inbox to All mail folder but I want it sent to Trash/Bin folder.

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import imaplib

imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
imap_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'
imap_pass = 'mypass'

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)

imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

status, data = imap.select('INBOX')

status, mail_id = imap.search(None, '(SUBJECT "My subject")')

status, msg_header = imap.fetch(mail_id[0], '(BODY[TEXT])')
saveFile = open('sample.txt',  'w')
saveFile.write(str(msg_header))
saveFile.close()

print "Received email body!"

# Delete the email
print "Deleting the email..."
imap.store(mail_id[0], '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
imap.expunge()
print "Email deleted!"
```

I want to save the email body into a new file then delete that email (There will be only one email on this email address).

Comment: You will need to identify the name of the Trash folder, then move the message there.  I believe there is an imap_move() function.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does not allow to delete emails directly from the INBOX.

They have mentioned complete email delete behaviour here
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78755?hl=en

In gmail imap store with delete flags works only for Trash and Spam.

**imap.store(mail_id[0], '+FLAGS', '\Deleted')**

It seems they made it intentionally for avoiding accidental deletes from the Inbox and custom folders.

If you want to delete email from Inbox or custom folders you need to apply Trash label to the email like this

. STORE 1 +X-GM-LABELS (\Trash)

Comment: This answer contradicts what Google says in the support document that you linked to. It is perfectly OK to send `UID STORE ... +FLAGS \Deleted`. The documentation says that the message will remain in the "All messages" virtual folder even after that, though.

Comment: I think "UID STORE ... +FLAGS \Deleted" does not work on emails from AllMail. Although "uid store" action is  sucess, Actually Gmail won't append "\Deleted" flags for AllMail emails.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic but i had the same problem and here my solution to move all the message in INBOX in gmail to the Trash

```
connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
connection.login("xxxxx@gmail.com", "password")
connection.select(mailbox='"INBOX"', readonly=False)
connection.store("1:*", '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')
connection.close()  # close and logout the connection
connection.logout()
```